# When should I use .set(..., clear=True) in Django?

Tags: python, django

Django's ManyToManyField managers have a [`.set(objs, bulk=True, clear=False)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set) method.

According to the [(current) source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10.6/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L934):

- `clear=True` calls `.clear` on the relation before adding everything in `objs`.
- `[clear=False]` fetches the related items to compare with `objs` and `.remove` everything not in `objs` then add anything in `objs` not in the relation already.

So in terms of database queries that gives us:

- `clear=True` sends 2 queries (one to delete everything, one to add all new items).
- `[clear=False]` sends up to m+n+1 queries (1 to get the existing relations, m to remove existing relations not in `objs` and n to add `objs` not in relations) as well as computing the difference between the sets.

The default `[clear=False]` seems much more inefficient. Why would I not set `clear=True` wherever I can? In what situations is the default behaviour preferable?

Comment: My guess is that it may be faster to fetch the relation and calculate the set difference in Python rather than perform database INSERTs. Another behaviour I ran into is that the [`m2m_changed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) `post_clear` and `pre_clear` actions both give an empty `pk_set` to avoid having to fetch from the database first, so idempotent operations I wanted to do on changed relations had to be run on all of them.